# Concept of RDD Operations in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, transformation

I am learning RDD concepts in detail and I got confused at one point. Lets say I am applying 3 map function back to back and then a filter function and finally a join. So here I am applying total 3 transformation which means 3 RDDs. But there is a catch here that is if my data is of size 10 TB and each map will give 10 TB RDD each which is 30 GB of data, which is not a feasible solution. After more reading I came to know that only one RDD will create in this process and I am not sure how it works.
So can anyone can provide me in depth detail on this.

Comment: The idea here is that all the `map` functions that you apply will be *fused* together and combined into a chain of function invocations on a single row. Look up the implementation of `map` on RDD for more details.

Comment: I understand that map will fused but but what about filter and join?

Comment: See https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-rdd-operations-transformations-actions/. Filter is also fused.